# Update Using CASE statement is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written the following code which is running but nothing is updated.

```
UPDATE FINDOC 
SET CCCPAPCUSCODE= 
(
CASE 
WHEN TRDBRANCH IS NULL THEN (SELECT TOP 1 CCCCODE1 FROM TRDBRANCH B WHERE     B.TRDBRANCH=TRDBRANCH) 
ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 CODE1 FROM TRDR T WHERE T.TRDR=TRDR) END 
) 
WHERE TRNDATE='20160226' AND 
SERIES IN (1001,1021,1502,1522,1009)
```

Can anyone suggest the reason?

Comment: Hence, nothing matches the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: What results do you get if you do a `SELECT * FROM FINDOC WHERE TRNDATE='20160226' AND SERIES IN (1001,1021,1502,1522,1009)`?

Comment: No, there are matches

Comment: What do you get if you do `select * from FINDOC where WHERE TRNDATE='20160226' AND 
SERIES IN (1001,1021,1502,1522,1009)`?

Comment: I got many lines of data

Comment: maybe the values are equal!? is this possible (the original values and the one you get from the case statement)

Comment: You should specify sort order for your `top 1`s and alias to `FINDDOC` since column names are equal in different tables.

Comment: Can you give an example of data that you would expect to be updated but is not?

Comment: @user2242558 `WHEN TRDBRANCH IS NULL THEN (SELECT TOP 1 CCCCODE1 FROM TRDBRANCH B WHERE     B.TRDBRANCH=TRDBRANCH)` does not make sense, select will return 0 rows always. May be here must be `WHEN TRDBRANCH IS NOT NULL THEN`?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like that:

```
UPDATE FD 
SET FD.CCCPAPCUSCODE = CASE 
                         WHEN FD.TRDBRANCH IS NULL THEN (SELECT TOP 1 CCCCODE1 FROM TRDBRANCH B WHERE B.TRDBRANCH=FD.TRDBRANCH) 
                         ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 CODE1 FROM TRDR T WHERE T.TRDR=FD.TRDR) 
                       END     
FROM  FINDOC FD
WHERE FD.TRNDATE='20160226' 
AND   FD.SERIES IN (1001,1021,1502,1522,1009)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic appears to be the wrong way round. Using @Megartron's version of your code, when `FD.TRDBRANCH` is `NULL` the subquery will not return any records and as result your update will do nothing. Did you mean to check for `NOT NULL` instead ? In that case the correct code would be:

```
UPDATE  FD
SET    FD.CCCPAPCUSCODE = CASE WHEN FD.TRDBRANCH IS NOT NULL
                          THEN ( SELECT TOP 1
                                       CCCCODE1
                                FROM       TRDBRANCH B
                                WHERE      B.TRDBRANCH = FD.TRDBRANCH
                              )
                          ELSE ( SELECT TOP 1
                                       CODE1
                                FROM       TRDR T
                                WHERE      T.TRDR = FD.TRDR
                              )
                      END
FROM       FINDOC FD
WHERE   FD.TRNDATE = '20160226'
       AND FD.SERIES IN ( 1001, 1021, 1502, 1522, 1009 )
```